# Where the data in PSFT_TREE_VERTICAL_FLATTENING come from?

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter, peoplesoft

I am using Informatica to extract tree hierarchy from Peoplesoft. I am trouble shooting some of the issue i have in the ETL.

I was able to trace all the way back to the mapping "SDE_PSFT_Stage_GLHierarchy_AccountHierarchy_Extract" and source table "PSFT_TREE_VERTICAL_FLATTENING", but i couldn't figure out where the data come from. The source table doesn't exists in the source environment nor target environment, and there are no SQL in the transformation.

I believe this is a deliver function, but I would like to know how the data are populated, or how can i see what's the SQL being run.

[image: PeopleSoft Source Qualifier]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I don't see any code that drop the table in the database. I can run this mapping and it ran to success with data populated to the target table. here is a screenshot of the mapping and table http://tinyurl.com/oz8yere

Comment: This is not a regular SQ but an Application Source Qualifier. It reads data directly from PeopleSoft that may expose a web service or have some product-specific way of providing access to data that this SQ that understand. Check the session for connection details.

Comment: I looked into the log there aren't much information. I am just wondering if you know where i can find the documentation for the Application Source Qualifier, or how can i customize it?

Comment: The document you need is PowerExchange for PeopleSoft User Guide. Use to [this link to search for an appropriate version](https://mysupport.informatica.com/search.jspa?q=powerexchange+for+peoplesoft+user+guide).